# How can I extract nested value in JSON and initialize to a JS variable

Tags: javascript, json, api

my question is above and I am trying like for 45mins to extract the value under "distance" below, but I fail at every try. I hope you guys can help me.

```
{
"destination_addresses": [
    "XXXXXXXX 60, 13XXX Berlin, Germany"
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "XXXXXXX Str. 67, 10XXX Berlin, Germany"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "10.4 km",
                    "value": 10365
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "21 min",
                    "value": 1278
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

So I need the value under rows --> elements --> distance then value. I tried something like this in JavaScript:

```
var payload = JSON.parse(body)
console.log(payload.rows["elements"].distance.value)
```

Thanks! :)

Süleyman Demir

Comment: thank you guys, you helped me :) the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
let distance = payload.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value
console.log(payload)
console.log(distance)
```

Please note that the data is a mix of nested arrays and objects, which are different data structures in javascript. You can access an object's property by typing its name followed by a dot and the name of the property (*object_name.property_name*). You can access  an array's element by typing the element index in square brackets next to the array's name *(array_name[element_number])*.

In our case we access the property "rows" which is an array of the object "payload" - *payload.rows*. Then we access the element number [0] of this array by typing [0] next to the property's name - *payload.rows[0]*. We get another object which has the property "elements" in it - *payload.rows[0].elements* . This property stores another array and we access its first element  again  -
*payload.rows[0].elements[0]*. We get another object and access the property "distance" which returns finally return another object that holds the property "value" we are looking for - *payload.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value*

Source https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not clear, I assume that you will have multiple rows and multiple elements. There is my solution according to what I understand.

```
payload.rows.forEach(x=> x.elements.forEach(y => console.log(y.distance.value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```js
var body = {
  "destination_addresses": ["XXXXXXXX 60, 13XXX Berlin, Germany"],
  "origin_addresses": ["XXXXXXX Str. 67, 10XXX Berlin, Germany"],
  "rows": [{
    "elements": [{
      "distance": {
        "text": "10.4 km",
        "value": 10365
      },
      "duration": {
        "text": "21 min",
        "value": 1278
      },
      "status": "OK"
    }]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
};

var payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));

payload.rows.forEach(row => row.elements.forEach(elem => console.log("Distance : ", elem.distance.value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want, but you can get the distance object with something like that:

```js
const payload = {
"destination_addresses": [
    "XXXXXXXX 60, 13XXX Berlin, Germany"
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "XXXXXXX Str. 67, 10XXX Berlin, Germany"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "10.4 km",
                    "value": 10365
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "21 min",
                    "value": 1278
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}

let distance = payload.rows[0].elements.map(element => {
    return {
        distance: element.distance
    }
});

// Map returns an array, so you can get the object using the index:

console.log(distance[0]);

// If you want only the value:

console.log(distance[0].distance.value);
```

If you want, you can also use Object.assign or something like that to avoid getting the value by the index.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
var payload = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(payload.rows[0]["elements"][0].distance.value);
```